# Closing a PostgreSQL Client Connection in Rust

Tags: postgresql, rust

I am new to Rust and I am using the Postgres crate. I am trying to create a wrapper around the PostgreSQL client, and I have defined this Struct:

```
pub struct PostGresSqlClient {
        user_name: String,
        host_name: String,
        port: String,
        client: Client,
    }
```

Later, I am trying to implement the Drop trait on this Struct. Right now, it just tries to close the connection to the Client, but later it may do different things.

```
impl Drop for PostGresSqlClient {
        fn drop(&mut self) {
            self.client.close();
        }
    }
```

However, I am running into this issue:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `self.client` which is behind a mutable reference
   --> data_lib/src/lib.rs:106:13
    |
106 |             self.client.close();
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `self.client` has type `Client`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I do not know how to resolve this and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Generally you don't need to implement `Drop` unless you are directly managing a raw resource yourself. In this case, the raw resource is managed by `Client`, so its `Drop` implementation would take care of it. Note that if your struct contains any members implementing `Drop`, the compiler will automatically implement `Drop` for your struct, delegating to the `Drop` implementation for each member.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to do it, from the [documentation](https://docs.rs/postgres/latest/postgres/struct.Client.html#method.close):

> Closes the client’s connection to the server.

> This is equivalent to Client’s Drop implementation, except that it returns any error encountered to the caller.

**The `Client` connection is already closed when dropped, and your inner `Client` will be dropped altogether with the outer one.**

Think that `close` takes an owned `Client` (`self`) which will be dropped after function call.